# How to center image in FloatingActionButton behind transparent background?

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, floating-action-button

I have a FloatingActionButton and I would like to make it transparent with a centered icon.

I added a style:

```
<style name="ButtonTransparent">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

which works so far. THe FAB got transparent. Then I added the FAB :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.CameraActivity">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_last_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonTransparent"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_vector_camera_light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonTransparent"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_vector_go_back" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but as you can see on the screenshot below it is not well aligned.
**How can I correct that?**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: android:scaleType="center"

Comment: parent layout of FloatingActionButton?

Comment: Please post full *layout* code. And also it will be great if you show what is current output and what will be your desired output.

Comment: @AliAhsan LinearLayout

Comment: @jaydroider Done, see OP

Comment: android:scaleType="center" to the FAB would do ?

Comment: sometimes, the icon may not come to center if you have set a custom width or height. make both wrap content and try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Image is positioned properly but the shadow in background no. If you press the button then it is even worse.

[image: transparent floating action button over oragne background]

To minimaze this effect you can change `elevation` and `pressedTranslationZ`

```
      app:elevation="1dp"
      app:borderWidth="0dp"
      app:pressedTranslationZ="1dp"
```

And you will get:

[image: effect after changing elevation and pressedTranslationZ]

Answer (score 104):

Use this attribute:
`app:fabCustomSize="60dp"`
make this equal to height and width of your fab. This helped me. This was my code.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_24dp" />
```

Another way could be using `android:foreground` attribute instead of `src` and then setting `android:foreground_gravity` to center.

Comment: Starting android P (support lib 28) fabCustomSite should equals width/height in order to display centered image content

Comment: also add `app:maxImageSize="60dp"` to fill the image in the FAB

Answer (score 11):

Just Write in your .Xml, inside your Fab

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:fabCustomSize="your-size"
app:maxImageSize="your-size"
```

It will work fine!!

Answer (score 11):

Hi, this works for me:

```
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
app:fabCustomSize="30dp"
```

add this line `app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/my_dimension"` and set the same value for these:

`android:layout_width="@dimen/my_dimension"`

`android:layout_height="@dimen/my_dimension"`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your back image/drawable is square in shape and this layout config worked for me 
[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back_vector" />
```

if you use

```
 app:backgroundTint="#200f"
```

The fab background tint color will look like the background thus will look a lot more transparent ..[image]

Comment: he want with transparent background

Comment: that is the shadow i think that comes with fab

Comment: that is the shadow i think that comes with fab

Comment: But one can make it look like transparent by selecting the bgtint color close to the background the fab will reside on with very less opacity for eg if the background is blue like mine then I  can set the tint bg as #100f

Answer (score 2):

Add this property , image will be centered automatically

```
app:fabSize="normal"
```

Comment: I tried everything, this was the only setting that centered the button!

Answer (score 0):

layout 2 files: such as 
content_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testbd.com.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testbd.com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and finally res/values/colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#5a1f00</color>
</resources>
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code.Hope it will help you. This code is working fine with me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingMap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_130dp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_directions"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

CoordinatorLayout is like a FrameLayout,So try below one.

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
```

Hope this will help.